# adding character on hover without moving text

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

Trying to add a character on hover, but I would like to do it without moving the text to right when the character appears.

If there would be a one static space character in front of each li I guess that would work but not sure how to accomplish this.
The code is below:

```css
ul{
   list-style:none;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    }

a:hover::before {
    content:'> ';
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Journalist</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Writer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Publications designer</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/bobqowde/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;    /* some value to give space for special letter */
}
a {
    position: relative;
}
a:hover::before {
    content:'> ';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;   /* equal to padding-left */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/bobqowde/3/)**

In the above fiddle, `padding-left` value should be equal to `left`.

Just for your understanding, you can also use `margin-left` instead of `padding-left` and also can apply to `li`